# Web UI Wrapper for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Are there any resources out there for wrapping access to DynamoDB in a web UI?

Currently, I have a Lambda function that will populate a Dynamo table via S3 trigger. However, I would like to allow my team access to items in a table without needing to go into DynamoDB or upload a file to the S3 console. I'm not sure what's needed to fulfill this requirement, so any references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would create API Gateway endpoints for each method you want to expose, have the API Gateway call your Lambda function to retrieve the data you want, and return that as JSON thru the API to your browser - and then use the JS framework of your choice to present it to the user (I use Angular and Bootstrap, but any JS/CSS would work as well).